# IPA transcriptions for Norwegian

Tags: ipa, transcription, norwegian

Are there online sources for Norwegian transcription?

[NAOB](https://naob.no) gives an orthographic one, [UiB Ordbokene](https://ordbok.uib.no) do not have transcription at all.

Answer (score 2):

One reason why there are not is that pronunciation is a bit dialect-idiosyncratic (*sverd* is [sʋæɖ] or [sʋæɾd], depending on dialect). Bokmål and Nynorsk are really written standards, and the 1sg pronoun has at least 3 pronunciations that I know (jæɪ, eɪ, æ). Kristoffersen's *The phonology of Norwegian* contains IPA for his dialect. Wiktionary does often include IPA, but they are more guided transliterations from spelling rather than actual transcriptions of pronunciation. Comparing Kristoffersen's practice with what you see in Wiktionary, you also see another factor, that they decided that Bokmål is /jæɪ̯/, not /jæɪ/ as I opted for (and then looked up their choice) – there are many ways to render the same pronunciation in IPA. They also list [kʋɪnə] for *kvinne* altough i  is clearly a geminate *n*, both /mɑn/ and /manː/ for *mann* (vs. /ɡrøːn/ for *grøn*), indicating a certain unsystematicity in their decisions regarding how to render long consonants.

The NAOB type transcriptions can be converted to IPA, as long as you accept that it isn't necessarily an actual pronunciation from a location.